# Cant run Python UDP server with OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, oop, udp

i Try to create udp port listener using OOP but i try to start server it not start. In python console it only show

```
=============RESTART: D:\server.py==================
>>>
```

this is my code

```
import threading
import time
import socket

class udpreceive:

   def __init__(self,port,ip):
       self.port = port
       self.ip = ip
       self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
       self.sock.bind((self.ip, self.port))

   def startserver(self):
       while True:
           time.sleep(1)
           data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
           print (data)
server1 = udpreceive(514,"192.168.1.5")
t1 =  threading.Thread(target=server1.startserver)
```

what is the error? I'm new to OOP and socket programming Thanks